# /web/template-files cannot be copied to own theme in order to modify them

Tags: magento2, luma-theme

If you try to translate the strings in `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/...` you need to modify them in the core directly. I do not want that.

Copying them is not a solution, since magento ignores the HTML files in the corresponding `/Magento_Checkout/web/template`-Folder.

Edit: it seems that the question is a little unclear for some. We want to modify the HTML-files in `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/`. Therefore we duplicate them into our own theme. Those changes are non-functional. Why and how can we fix it?

Comment: Show us how you're trying to translate them?  You should be able to do it with a file called "translate.csv" if you look up your template locale file.

Comment: I am using a CSV in app/i18n/..., but this also does not render. Can you specify where you'd place the translate.csv?

Comment: Most likely that this solution is for 1.9, or not? Never seen a locale-Folder in the frontend file structure before... But am curious about that!

Comment: This question is not about "how to translate strings in general", its something else. Thanks for your effort anyway.